# Update a record multiple times by a function with arguments from a list

Tags: f#

What I have:

```
type Item = 
  {
    Name : string
  }

type Model = 
  { 
    Items : Item list
  }

let init = {
  Items = []
  }

type Msg =
  |AddItem
  |DoNothing

let update msg model =  //Msg -> Model -> Model
  match msg with
  |AddItem -> {model with Items = List.append [{Name = "NewItem"}] model.Items}
  |DoNothing -> model

let rec apply f model list = //(a' -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
        match list with
        |[] -> model
        |head::tail -> let model' = f head model
                       apply f model' tail

let msgs = [AddItem; DoNothing; AddItem]

let model' = apply update init msgs
```

gives the result:

```
val model' : Model = { Items = [{ Name = "NewItem" }; { Name = "NewItem" }] }
```

I have checked *fold*, *map* and some others, but it looks like non of these functions is doing the same as my *apply*.

Is there a built-in function in *List* or somewhere else which is the same as my *apply*? Because if there is, I would rather use that one.

Comment: This looks the same as `List.fold` with the arguments to `f` in the other order i.e. `List.fold (fun model msg -> update msg model) init msgs`

Comment: @Lee Perfect! Make this an answer and I will accept it. Man, really hard to see, for a noob like me, how to use the standard functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `apply` function is the same as `List.fold` with the arguments to the accumulator function in a different order. The type of `apply` is:

```
(a' -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

and the type of `List.fold` is:

```
(b' -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

so you can replace your call to `apply` with:

```
List.fold (fun model msg -> update msg model) init msgs
```